# Merging with respect to bounded uniformly continuous functions in terms of characteristic functions

Tags: probability, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

I would like to know if there are any results, where merging 
of probability measures in $R^n$ with respect to bounded uniformly continuous functions is deduced from some conditions on characteristic functions?

In partucular, is it true that if for all t $f_n(t)-g_n(t)$ converges to zero, when $n$ goes to infinity, where $f_n(t)=\int e^{itx} dP_n(x)$ and $g_n(t)=\int e^{itx} dQ_n(x)$, then sequences of measures $P_n$ and $Q_n$ merge wrt bounded uniformly continuous functions?

(sequences $P_n$ and $Q_n$ of probability measures merge wrt bounded uniformly continuous functions if for every bounded uniformly continuous function $f$ $(\int f dP_n)-(\int f dQ_n)$ converges to zero when n goes to infinity)

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have defined merging for sequences of probability measures and you are asking if sequences of sets merge.

Comment: Sorry for improperly formulating the question. I have edited it, is it now easier to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counterexample is given in R.M.Dudley, "Real analysis and probability"(proposition 11.7.6). Take $P_n$ with density $\frac{1}{x\cdot log(n)}$ on the interval $[1,n]$. Take $dQ_n(x)=dP_n(-x)$. And take $f(x)=max(0,min(x,1))$, for example.